# Tag Synonym request: [patch] → [update]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I'd like to request that [patch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/patch) be made a synonym of [update](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update). Or the other way.

While I know these are not synonymous in terms of functionality (a patch by definition will alter, rewrite, or remove files during the patching process), and update is a more fluid meaning (it could be a patch or just a new file to read from); In the end they both mean the same thing: Your game gets a shiny new version number and hopefully your head doesn't explode when you push <kbd>jump</kbd> (unless of course you are playing *Eternal Darkness*).

Answer (score 1):

I found that [update](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update) was a really weak tag at only ~8 questions, 3 or 4 of which were already closed.

I just edited away that tag, and we can go with the [patch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/patch) for now.